# How do I get the Value out of my Class into my TextViewField

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

At the moment I am trying to make an Android App with Android Studio with GET and POST data into/from an API.

My problem at the moment is that I want to have the response of the POST request displayed in my app. For this I made the TextView TW_Rueckgabe. I also made another Method just for this so it can Display the Request which is

```
public String returnString() {
        return fetching_data;
    }
```

but the response is not saved in TW_Rueckgabe.

MainActivity.java

```
final TextView[] TW_Rueckgabe = {findViewById(R.id.textViewRueckgabe)};

Button sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String POST_url = "http://dphost.ddns.net:1573/cool/post.php";
            String requestData = "data=" + TW_Benutzername.getText().toString();
            POSTRequestTask test = (POSTRequestTask) new POSTRequestTask().execute(POST_url, requestData);

            

            TW_Rueckgabe[0].setText(test.fetching_data);

        });
```

POSTRequestTask Class:

```
class POSTRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        String requestData = params[1];
        String response = "";

        try {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // add request header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            // add request data
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(requestData);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBuffer.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            response = responseBuffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // print result
        System.out.println("\n\n\n" + result + "\n\n\n");
        fetching_data = result;
        
    }

public String returnString() {
        return fetching_data;
    }
}
```

I tried to make a new Object and then save the Variable from the Object, didn't work.

Comment: I think you are just setting value to your text view "not in the right place"
your fetching_data = result is running only when your request response is received
you just need to move "TW_Rueckgabe[0].setText(test.fetching_data);" this code into the onPostExecute method of your AsyncTask class implementation, it will be better if you would create some callback and when onPostExecute is executes call callback method wich will handle your MainActivity and inside that callback implementation set your data to text view

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Callback {
   void onResponse(String response);
}

MainActivity {

   private Callback callback = new Callback() {
       @Override
       void onResponse(String response) {
            TW_Rueckgabe[0].setText(test.fetching_data);
       }
   }

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String POST_url = "http://dphost.ddns.net:1573/cool/post.php";
            String requestData = "data=" + TW_Benutzername.getText().toString();
            POSTRequestTask test = new POSTRequestTask(callback).execute(POST_url, requestData);
        });
}


class POSTRequestTask(Callback callback) extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       // do your request as you're doing now and return the result
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // callback interface method call here
        callback.onResponse(result)
    }
}
```